# Stripe test payment and saving order simultaneously not working

Tags: laravel-5.3

> I am working with stripe test payment and want to store my order in db also but facing an error i.e.

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

> My controller is Checkout function

```
    public function postCheckOut(Request $request){
        if(!Session::has('cart')){
            return redirect()->route('shop.cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

        /* Stripe Test Api key */
        Stripe::setApiKey('-------');
        try{
          $charge =  \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => $cart->totalPrice * 100,
                "currency" => "usd",
//                "source" => "$request->input('stripeToken')", // obtained with Stripe.js
                'card' => array(
                    'number' => $request->get("cnumber"),
                    'exp_month' => $request->get("exp-month"),
                    'exp_year' => $request->get("exp-year"),
                    'cvc' => $request->get("cvc"),
                ),
                "description" => "product purchased"
            ));
            /* Saving order data after purchasing done */
            $order = new Order();
            $order->user_id = Auth::id();
            $order->cart = serialize($cart);
            $order->address = $request->input('address');
            $order->name = $request->input('name');
            $order->payment_id = $charge->id;
//            dd($order);exit;
            /* Saving order data by orm relation calling login user then its order function and then save orders */
            Auth::user()->orders->save($order);

        } catch (\Exception $e){
            return redirect()->route('checkout')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
        Session::forget('cart');
        return redirect()->route('product.index')->with('success', 'Product purchased');
    }
```

> please guide what i am doing wrong. I check almost what i can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are already getting value for `foreign key` Try directly storing it like this

```
$order->save();
```

else you can also try this

```
Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
```

instead of

```
Auth::user()->orders->save($order);
```

Refer to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)